# Where is the shift/reduce conflict in this grammar?

Tags: shift-reduce-conflict

Can't seem to figure out what's causing the shift/reduce conflict in this grammar. It seems to be fixed with assigning rightmost operator precedence to CMD and LCURLY, yet I do not know exactly what the problem is. Any help?

```
ContentList : Content
            | Content ContentList
;

Content : CMD
        | CMD LCURLY TEXT RCURLY
        | LCURLY CMD WS TEXT RCURLY
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use yacc's `-v` option to get more details of the generated grammar.  This gives you a .output file that contains something like:

```
State 1 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
       :
state 1

    3 Content: CMD .
    4        | CMD . LCURLY TEXT RCURLY

    LCURLY  shift, and go to state 5

    LCURLY    [reduce using rule 3 (Content)]
    $default  reduce using rule 3 (Content)
```

which shows you exactly where the problem is.  In this case, after seeing a `CMD`, when the next token is `LCURLY` it doesn't know whether to reduce the 3rd rule (`Content: CMD`) so it can then start parsing something that will match the 5th rule, or whether to shift the `LCURLY` to continue to match the 4th rule.

In this case, it could tell with more lookahead (2 tokens would be enough -- the decision would be made on whether the token after the `LCURLY` was a `TEXT` or a `CMD`), but yacc (and most LR parser generators) only use one token of lookahead.